# Hot to mock functions with different types of return values?

Tags: typescript, jestjs

I use Jest for writing unit-tests on NodeJS. There is a method which can return one entity or array of entities. When I try to mock returned value of this method I just can pass array, but need one entity.

`npm i jest typeorm`

```
const manager = new EntityManager(null);
const sale = new Sale();
jest.spyOn(manager, 'create').mockReturnValue(sale);
```

Last string causes error:
`Argument of type 'Sale' is not assignable to parameter of type '{}[]'. Type 'Sale' is missing the following properties from type '{}[]': length, pop, push, concat, and 26 more.`

Comment: Why you want to do that? Make mock return like the same origin function `mockReturnValue([sale]); `, or force the return value `.mockReturnValue(sale as any);  `

Comment: Origin method `EntityManager.create` can return both: `[sale]` or `sale`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use withArgs to achieve this,

**withArgs(…args) →**

Specifies a strategy to be used for calls to the spy that have the specified arguments

Eg:

```
spyOn(something, 'func').withArgs(arg1).returnValue(obj);
```

Then again spyOn with different for different returnValue

```
spyOn(something, 'func').withArgs(arg2).returnValue(arrayValue);
```

Comment: With `spyOn(manager, 'create').withArgs(saleDto).mockReturnValue(sale);` I get `Property 'withArgs' does not exist on type 'Spy'.`

Comment: Make sure you are using spyOn from jasmine import